# How to extract data from two tables using SQL object relational statement in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to solve the following query using object relational approach but don't know what is the proper way.

**Find the number of saving accounts at each branch, displaying the
number and branch’s address.**

I created two tables and insert some data like this:

--THIS IS BRANCH TABLE:

```
create type Branch_Address as object(
street varchar2(20),
city varchar2(20),
p_code varchar2(10))
not final
/

create type Branch_Phone as object(
phone varchar2(20))
not final;
/

create type branch_type as object(
bID varchar2(10),
bAddress Branch_Address,
bPhone Branch_Phone)
/

create table branch of branch_type(
primary key (bID))
/

insert into branch values(
'901',Branch_Address('Nic Street','Jordan','ABH887A'),Branch_Phone('0335454888'));
/
insert into branch values(
'906',Branch_Address('East End Garden','California','L181QP'),Branch_Phone('07455668711'));
/
insert into branch values(
'912',Branch_Address('Fredrick Street','London','LA112AS'),Branch_Phone('02841124478'));
/

insert into branch values(
'924',Branch_Address('West Street','Cambridge','CA8L871'),Branch_Phone('04511477885'));
```

--This is account table

```
create type account_type as object(
accNum int,
accType varchar2(15),
balance number, 
bID ref branch_type,
inRate number,
limitOfFreeOD number,
openDate DATE)
/
create table account_table of account_type(
primary key (accNum))
/

insert into account_table
select account_type('1001','current','820.50',ref(b),'0.005','800','01-May-11')
from branch b
where b.bID = '901';
/

insert into account_table 
select account_type('1010','saving','2155',ref(b),'0.02','0','08-Mar-10')
from branch b
where b.BID = '906';
/
insert into account_table 
select account_type('1002','current','2600',ref(b),'0.005','1000','10-Apr-13')
from branch b
where b.BID = '912';
/
insert into account_table 
select account_type('1112','saving','24000',ref(b),'0','1700','16-Jun-16')
from branch b
where b.BID = '924';
/
```

Branch(**bID**, street, city, p_code, bPhone)

Account(**accNum**, accType, balance, *bID*, inRate, limitOfFreeOD, openDate)

Bold is primary key
Italic is foreign key (In object relational we don't use Join if I am right).

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can join those:

```
select b.bid, 
    (select count(1) from account_table a 
      where a.bid.bid = b.bid
      and a.acctype='saving'
      ) as num_accounts,
    b.baddress.street, b.baddress.city, b.baddress.p_code 
from branch b;
```

This is more confusing because `branch_type.bID` is a `varchar2(10)` and `account_type.bID` is a `ref branch_type`. I would rename bID on account_type to something like `accBranch` to be more clear that it does not store the ID, but is a reference to the entire object.

I haven't tested this query, but you can also write this as a join (below) instead of a subquery (above). They each have their uses.

```
select b.bid, count(1) as num_accounts,
    b.baddress.street, b.baddress.city, b.baddress.p_code 
from branch b
join account_table a
  on a.bid.bid = b.bid
  and a.acctype='saving'
group by b.bid, b.baddress.street, b.baddress.city, b.baddress.p_code;
```

Comment: To extract only saving account, should I use " where a.acctype='saving' "after the last line? And Thanks for the massive help and explanation.

Comment: I edited to include a filter on accType, and also added a second version as a join instead of a subquery. lmk if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you. It's work like a magic. Just saying, will you be able to help me few more queries?

Comment: If you have other queries you'd like help with, you should probably post them as separate questions. I'm no expert, but I'll try to help out. :)

Comment: I am sure you can help me. Can I send you on Email?

Comment: scorpio_039@yahoo.com can I have your Email here? Thanks.

Comment: In this question I think in customer table customerid can act PK as well as FK with account_table. Please see the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266565/how-to-extract-data-from-three-tables-using-sql-object-relational-statement-in-o

Comment: Hiya, how are you? can you help me in this question? thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374140/how-to-write-sql-statement-when-use-method-in-object-relational-database