# How to write SQL statement when use Method in object relational database

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to create a small database of bank employees using **method** in oracle 11g, so at the end I can fetch values of those employees who are entitle for the awards at the end of the year:

Gold medals for employees who have been working at the bank for more than 12 years and supervised more than 6 staff; silver medals for employees who have been working at the bank for more than 8 years and supervised more than 3 staff; bronze medals for employees who have been working at the bank for
more than 4 years, displaying their names and Medal awarded (only
displaying those who have been awarded).

**So here what I am doing**

```
create type EmployeeName as object(
title varchar2(10),
firstName varchar2(20),
surname varchar2(20))
not final
/
create or replace type employeeaward as object(
empID integer,
eName EmployeeName,
number_staff_supervised int,
working_years int,
MEMBER FUNCTION award_given RETURN STRING,
MEMBER FUNCTION number_fraction (N real) RETURN real
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY employeeaward AS
MEMBER FUNCTION award_given RETURN STRING IS
BEGIN
IF self.working_years > 12 THEN
RETURN 'gold medal';
ELSIF self.working_years > 8 THEN
RETURN 'silver medal';
ELSIF self.working_years > 4 THEN
RETURN 'bronze medals';
END IF;
END award_given;
MEMBER FUNCTION number_fraction(N real) RETURN real IS
num real;
BEGIN
num :=(self.number_staff_supervised);
return num;
END number_fraction;
END;
```

**and then create a table employeeawardtable of employeeaward like this:**

```
create table employeeawardtable of employeeaward;
/
```

**Then insert some values in the table**

```
insert into employeeawardtable values('2001',EmployeeName('Mr','Rohit','Sharma'),'12','18');
/
insert into employeeawardtable values('2002',EmployeeName('Mr','Andrew','Darson'),'9','7');
/
insert into employeeawardtable values('2003',EmployeeName('Mrs','Sarah','Barlow'),'5','4');
/
insert into employeeawardtable values('2004',EmployeeName('Mr','Ram','Gopal'),'11','9');
/
```

**This is the SQL query, I am struggling to fetch data. **

```
select e.ename.firstname, e.award_given(),e.number_fraction(15)
from employeeawardtable e
where e.number_fraction() > 8;
```

Thanks.

Comment: select e.ename.firstname, e.award_given(),e.number_fraction(15)
from employeeawardtable e
where e.number_fraction(15) > 8;

Comment: The error I got executing your sql was "ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'NUMBER_FRACTION'". Passed 15 to number_fraction in predicate, same as in your select clause.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the issues with your code.

1. The number_fraction member function is invoked without a parameter in the predicate. This will throw an error, `"ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'NUMBER_FRACTION'"`

Below is SQL for your requirement.

```
select e.ename.firstname, e.award_given()
from employeeawardtable e
where e.award_given() = 'gold medal' and e.number_staff_supervised > 6
or e.award_given() = 'silver medal' and e.number_staff_supervised > 3
or e.award_given() = 'bronze medal';
```

2. The member_function award_given is not returning a default value. This will throw an error. `"ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value"`. Fix the type body as below.

   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY employeeaward AS
   MEMBER FUNCTION award_given RETURN STRING IS
   BEGIN
   IF self.working_years > 12 THEN
   RETURN 'gold medal';
   ELSIF self.working_years > 8 THEN
   RETURN 'silver medal';
   ELSIF self.working_years > 4 THEN
   RETURN 'bronze medals';
   **ELSE--newly added
   RETURN 'no medal';--newly added**
   END IF;
   END award_given;
   MEMBER FUNCTION number_fraction(N real) RETURN real IS
   num real;
   BEGIN
   num :=(self.number_staff_supervised);
   return num;
   END number_fraction;
   END;

Now issue the SQL.
Output:

```
ENAME.FIRSTNAME E.AWARD_GIVEN()
Rohit           gold medal
Ram             silver medal
```

Comment: What an amazing explanation. Thank you so much. Do you teach as well?

Comment: Thanks. I am just a programmer.